# Resizing two views using auto layout

Tags: ios, autolayout

Is it possible to resize two views related to each other? I have a custom view (grey rectangle) and a collection view (black view with green square).

[image: Auto layout]

I'd like the grey view to be 80pts tall in portrait, but shrink down to a minimum of 54pts in landscape. The collection view should just use whatever remaining space there is.

If I fix the height of the grey view, I can set up constraints so that the collection view occupies the remaining space, but in landscape the grey view is just too large.

Comment: Have you set any height constraints on the views?

Comment: Setting fixed height constraints mean the views don't resize the way I'd like. For example, if I fix the grey view at 80 pts it looks fine in portrait, but too large in landscape.

Comment: Why dont you update the constraint on orientation?

Comment: If I were going to do that I'd probably just do the layout by hand and avoid autolayout. I'm trying to keep my controller as clean as possible - avoiding layout based code as much as possible.

Comment: it definitely seems like this might be the only option..

Comment: Surely you'd end up with a lot more code if you do the whole layout by hand as opposed to setting one constraint constant on rotation?

Comment: Oh absolutely! I suppose I was just frustrated as I really struggle getting auto-layout to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use height constraints where you have both `>=` and `<=`. These should specify that the grey view is at least your minimum and not more than your maximum, and that the black view is at least the minimum space available in the landscape view (this is what will push the grey view smaller in landscape, but it will be larger in portrait as there is more room).

Comment: If I add both `>= 54` `<= 80` to the grey view, and have the black view flexible width/height, it just keeps the grey view at 80pts and makes the collection view smaller.

Comment: You need a minimum height on the collection view too

Comment: If I add a minimum height to the collection view the constraints break (turn orange). If I keep it as a static height, the constraints stay blue, although obviously this doesn't work.